# What happened to Html.ActionLink<TController> in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm reading all of these blogs about using the Html.ActionLink method with lambda expressions.  I even saw a ScottGu presentation about it here: http://www.hanselman.com/silverlight/ScottGuAtAltNetConf/

Here's a blog: http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-preview-using-the-mvc-ui-helpers/

Here's a ScottGu blog about it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

"Can also be written as:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Search Drinks", s => s.Results("Beverages", 2)) %>
```

"

With this being such a powerful way to write URL routes - ESPECIALLY since it automatically supports refactoring tools - why is this either apparently missing or so hard to find?  I looked at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions in Reflector and I see plenty of ActionLink(this HtmlHelper...) extension methods, but none that are generic.

Anyone have help?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got moved out to the Futures assembly (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll) as, from what I understand, there were some issues the dev team needed to sort through.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471

Comment: Thank you!  I could not find this for the life of me!

Comment: Tha problem afaik was that you could rename the controllers using attributes from prewiev 5 and upto, and this was incompatible with this implementation

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be included in [ASP.NET MVC Futures](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16775).

So I guess the answer is just that it didn't quite make it into the first release.